# Flatten records into a single row where values are not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, sql-server-2016, flatten

I know there's a bunch of "Flatten" questions, but they don't seem to fit this requirement.

Given a table of data with 4 columns, all of which can have null's, I need to be able to specify a specific depth value and get a single record back that will search at that depth and lower (towards 1) to fill in the gaps.

```
COL1      COL2          COL3         COL4   DEPTH
--------- ------------- ------------ ------ -----------
NULL      NULL          Manager      NULL   9
NULL      NULL          NULL         NULL   8
Jack      NULL          NULL         36     7
NULL      NULL          Employed     28     6
James     NULL          NULL         15     5
NULL      Ericson       NULL         NULL   4
NULL      NULL          NULL         23     3
Jack      NULL          NULL         NULL   2
John      Smith         Unemployed   45     1
```

Requesting a depth of 5 for example, should return:

```
COL1      COL2        COL3           COL4   DEPTH
--------- ----------- -------------- ------ -----
James     Ericson     Unemployed     15     5
```

Sample setup:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    [COL1] varchar(30) NULL,
    [COL2] varchar(30) NULL,
    [COL3] varchar(30) NULL,
    [COL4] varchar(30) NULL,
    [DEPTH] int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT Null     , Null      , 'Manager'     , Null  , 9 UNION ALL
SELECT Null     , Null      , Null          , Null  , 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack'   , Null      , Null          , '36'  , 7 UNION ALL
SELECT Null     , Null      , 'Employed'    , '28'  , 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'James'  , Null      , Null          , '15'  , 5 UNION ALL
SELECT Null     , 'Ericson' , Null          , Null  , 4 UNION ALL
SELECT Null     , Null      , Null          , '23'  , 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack'   , Null      , Null          , Null  , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'John'   , 'Smith'   , 'Unemployed'  , '45'  , 1;

SELECT * FROM @Table ORDER BY DEPTH DESC;
```

Current working code:

```
DECLARE @Depth int = 5;
SELECT 
    [COL1] = ( SELECT TOP(1) [COL1] FROM @Table WHERE [DEPTH] <= @Depth AND [COL1] IS NOT Null ORDER BY DEPTH DESC ),
    [COL2] = ( SELECT TOP(1) [COL2] FROM @Table WHERE [DEPTH] <= @Depth AND [COL2] IS NOT Null ORDER BY DEPTH DESC ),
    [COL3] = ( SELECT TOP(1) [COL3] FROM @Table WHERE [DEPTH] <= @Depth AND [COL3] IS NOT Null ORDER BY DEPTH DESC ),
    [COL4] = ( SELECT TOP(1) [COL4] FROM @Table WHERE [DEPTH] <= @Depth AND [COL4] IS NOT Null ORDER BY DEPTH DESC );
```

Is there a better way to retrieve the data?  I've tried a few things but nothing else has even worked, let alone better.

Comment: Thank you very much for the well articulated question including a full [mcve], your own attempts and the expected output. That is how it should be... +1 from my side

Comment: I try, sometimes it's hard to describe it all and sometimes you don't always manage a minimal example.  I never understand why people still downvote me, I wish they'd just take the time to let me know so I can improve.  Never the less, thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a XML trick:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(COL1 VARCHAR(100),COL2 VARCHAR(100),COL3 VARCHAR(100),COL4 INT,DEPTH INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (NULL,NULL   ,'Manager',NULL,9)
,(NULL,NULL   ,NULL   ,NULL,8)
,('Jack',NULL   ,NULL   ,36  ,7)
,(NULL,NULL   ,'Employed',28  ,6)
,('James',NULL   ,NULL   ,15  ,5)
,(NULL,'Ericson',NULL   ,NULL,4)
,(NULL,NULL   ,NULL   ,23  ,3)
,('Jack',NULL   ,NULL   ,NULL,2)
,('John','Smith'  ,'Unemployed',45  ,1);

DECLARE @dpth INT=5;

WITH DataAsXml(TheXml) AS
(
    SELECT t.*
    FROM @tbl t
    WHERE t.DEPTH<=@dpth
    ORDER BY t.DEPTH DESC  
    FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
)
SELECT TheXml.value('(/row/COL1/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS COL1 
      ,TheXml.value('(/row/COL2/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS COL2
      ,TheXml.value('(/row/COL3/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS COL3
      ,TheXml.value('(/row/COL4/text())[1]','int') AS COL4
      ,TheXml.value('(/row/DEPTH/text())[1]','int') AS DEPTH
FROM DataAsXml;
```

The intermediate XML looks like this:

```
<row>
  <COL1>James</COL1>
  <COL4>15</COL4>
  <DEPTH>5</DEPTH>
</row>
<row>
  <COL2>Ericson</COL2>
  <DEPTH>4</DEPTH>
</row>
<row>
  <COL4>23</COL4>
  <DEPTH>3</DEPTH>
</row>
<row>
  <COL1>Jack</COL1>
  <DEPTH>2</DEPTH>
</row>
<row>
  <COL1>John</COL1>
  <COL2>Smith</COL2>
  <COL3>Unemployed</COL3>
  <COL4>45</COL4>
  <DEPTH>1</DEPTH>
</row>
```

As you can see, XML will omit NULL values by default. The code will sort the list in **descending** order. Using XQuery to fetch **the very first value** will return the top-most, non-null value.

Comment: This is the one I was after, I matched my attempt against yours and was surprised to see how close I had gotten. It was the XQuery that tripped me up a bit, I know that XML omits Nulls by default and I should have used that to my advantage.  Thanks for this!

Comment: Oh, I believe your first SELECT within the WITH is superfluous.

Comment: @Storm You are right about the superfluous `SELECT`. That's a bit counter intutitive actually, but better to read without. I've changed that...

Answer (score 1):

I really like Shnugo's solution, but by the time I've seen it I came up with another one, admittedly more cumbersome solution - using a couple of common table expressions and conditional aggregation - so I'm posting it here just because I don't want the time I spent on it feel like a total waist:

```
DECLARE @Depth int = 5;

WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, DEPTH,
       SIGN(SUM(IIF(COL1 IS NULL, 0, 1)) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC)) AS NonNull1, 
       SIGN(SUM(IIF(COL2 IS NULL, 0, 1)) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC)) AS NonNull2, 
       SIGN(SUM(IIF(COL3 IS NULL, 0, 1)) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC)) AS NonNull3, 
       SIGN(SUM(IIF(COL4 IS NULL, 0, 1)) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC)) AS NonNull4
FROM @Table 
WHERE DEPTH <= @Depth
), CTE2 AS 
(
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, DEPTH,
        SUM(NonNull1) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC) As S1,
        SUM(NonNull2) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC) As S2,
        SUM(NonNull3) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC) As S3,
        SUM(NonNull4) OVER(ORDER BY Depth DESC) As S4
FROM CTE1
)

SELECT  MAX(IIF(S1 = 1, Col1, NULL)) As Col1,
        MAX(IIF(S2 = 1, Col2, NULL)) As Col2,
        MAX(IIF(S3 = 1, Col3, NULL)) As Col3,
        MAX(IIF(S4 = 1, Col4, NULL)) As Col4,
        MAX(DEPTH) As Depth
FROM CTE2
```

The first cte adds columns containing 0 until the first non-null value appears, then 1.
The second cte sums these columns, so S1, S2 etc' will contain 0, 1, 2... etc'.
The final selects only values where S1, S2 etc' equals 1 - which is the first non-null value of each column.

Comment: I always like getting your insights Zohar, appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: Glad I can help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this as another answer as it follows a completely different idea:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(COL1 VARCHAR(100),COL2 VARCHAR(100),COL3 VARCHAR(100),COL4 INT,DEPTH INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (NULL,NULL   ,'Manager',NULL,9)
,(NULL,NULL   ,NULL   ,NULL,8)
,('Jack',NULL   ,NULL   ,36  ,7)
,(NULL,NULL   ,'Employed',28  ,6)
,('James',NULL   ,NULL   ,15  ,5)
,(NULL,'Ericson',NULL   ,NULL,4)
,(NULL,NULL   ,NULL   ,23  ,3)
,('Jack',NULL   ,NULL   ,NULL,2)
,('John','Smith'  ,'Unemployed',45  ,1);

DECLARE @dpth INT=5;
```

--A recursive CTE will travers down the lines to fetch (and hold) the first non-null value:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.DEPTH DESC) AS RowIndex
    FROM @tbl t
    WHERE t.DEPTH<=@dpth
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS rwInx, cte.* FROM cte WHERE RowIndex=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rc.rwInx+1
          ,ISNULL(rc.COL1,c.COL1) AS COL1
          ,ISNULL(rc.COL2,c.COL2) AS COL2
          ,ISNULL(rc.COL3,c.COL3) AS COL3
          ,ISNULL(rc.COL4,c.COL4) AS COL4
          ,ISNULL(rc.DEPTH,c.DEPTH) AS DEPTH
          ,c.RowIndex
    FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN recCTE rc ON c.RowIndex=rc.rwInx+1
)
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY RowIndex DESC;
```

Hint: Take away the `TOP 1` to observe the progressive "filling" of the list.

Comment: haha, I also started with a CTE (it felt like the natural first choice for this) but at one point I had to take a step back and say "that ****s getting too complicated, there must be a simpler way" :P